# psfragfig pdflatex image shifted and cropped

Tags: matlab, psfrag, pdfcrop

Some images inserted with `psfragfig`, are shifted to one side (right) and partially placed off the document. (see image, bottom figure is the one I'm talking about).
[image]

It occurs with TexShop whether I use `pdflatex` (using `--shell-escape`) or Tex+DVI.

The code I'm using to insert is :

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \psfragfig{./figures/chapter1/intrinsic_error} % Generated by script_errors.m
    \caption{Blah...}
    \label{intrinsic_error}
\end{figure}
```

As you can guess, the image was generated by Matlab, using subplot and a tool called `matlabfrag` which generated the `.tex` file along with the `.eps` file. 
However, I have no problem with single-plot images inserted with the same code.
Maybe `matlabfrag` is messing with the alignment properties in an incorrect way, but is there a workaround to simply shift the image back to the left with some `psfragfig` options ? 
Or should I use another tool to insert ?

Thanks for your help

Update : working example . The above would be inserted in :

Here is a working example... It's a PhD thesis, so not sure if the sample will be "enough" to understand my pb.

```
\documentclass[braunschweig]{thesis}

\usepackage[style=base,textfont={small,it},labelfont={it,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage[tight,scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pstool}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You might have a look to [our start page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436): it will help you to familiarize with the site.

Comment: Is it possible to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your situation starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Guess: Use `[crop=pdfcrop]` in `pstool` I did not ever try `subplot` in matlab instead used `subfig` or `subcaption`. Try `\psfragfig[scale=0.5]{}` can use `angle`, `scale` and some options of `graphicx`.

Comment: I can't write a working example in the comment. i'm limited by the number of characters. i'll try answering my own question.

Comment: Bullseye ! Using [crop=pdfcrop] in pstool fixed it !
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Comment that worked for OP made into answer:

Use `[crop=pdfcrop]` while loading [`pstool`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/pstool.pdf), I have not used `subplot` in Matlab instead used `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Try `\psfragfig[scale=0.5]{}` that can use angle, scale and some options of graphicx.